# Create two-dimensional String Array from existing, without specific "row"

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Assume I have a two-dimenstional String Array with the following row:

```
table[0][0] = "Tom";
table[0][1] = "Baker";
table[0][2] = "TimeLord";
```

I have a challenge to remove a specific row from the array where the user types in any element from the row. The actual two-dim. array I have is read from a resultset. I have to do the above without using ArrayLists and without using any external libraries/api.

How can I do this? (Efficiency does not matter here)

Comment: Create a new array with one less row than the input array and copy the rest of the rows from the input array.

Comment: Will this work if, for argument sake, the specified row is row 5/100?

Comment: Of course. You'll have to copy the first 4 rows to the new array, skip the 5th and then copy the remaining 95 rows.

Comment: Do you mean that if you Array is a 1X3 size array (like in the illustration), after removing a row (let's say table [0][1]), we will then have a 1X2 size array made of table[0][0] = "Tom" and table[0][1] = "TimeLord"?

Comment: Bad example, Here's a sanitised version of the database table:

`id|Username|Password|UserType|Full Name|Age|DOB|Location|Record_Created`
`1|tomBaker|Tardis|admin|Tom Baker|20|1994-11-11|Time Vortex|<auto-inserted from front-end application>`

Ideally, I would be able to remove this entire row from the array, then upload the updated table to the database

Comment: Likely you should seperate updating a displayed list (e.g. by removing a row from an array) and updateing the database. The database does not need to knoe, which rows are still there, but which row was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you were to accept the Java explanation of a two-dimensional array.

from the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> In the Java programming language, a multidimensional array is an array
>   whose components are themselves arrays.

So were you to remove a particular "row" you are just removing an array at that position.
and then modify the array accordingly.

This would be followed by using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int%29) which would then perform the copying operation and remove the required row. i.e. :

```
        int[][] tester={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
        int row=2;
        System.out.println(tester.length);
        System.arraycopy(tester, row+1, tester, row, tester.length-row-1);
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

**EDIT**:The last 2 "rows" would be a copy of each other.you would still have to delete the last one.

```
    int[][] tester={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8}};
    int row=2;
    int[][] testerCopy=new int[tester.length-1][tester[0].length];
    System.out.println(tester.length);
    System.arraycopy(tester, row+1, tester, row, tester.length-row-1);
    System.arraycopy(tester, 0, testerCopy, 0, testerCopy.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testerCopy[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testerCopy[1]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testerCopy[2]));
    System.out.println(testerCopy.length);
```